# Make a blank response in twilio webhook

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

How can I make a blank response in twilio using php/laravel?

Here is a sample Twiml:
`<Response></Response>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code that I have come up with (I'm using laravel):

```
public function receivedSms(){
    $response = new Twiml();

    return response($response)
      ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using twilio api packages for aspnet.core you can return NoContent() on your api end-points.

```
[ValidateTwilioRequest]
[Produces("text/xml")]
[HttpPost("userresponse")]
public IActionResult ReceiveSMS() 
{
// do your action for the received response
return NoContent();
}
```